# How can I disable access to specific javascript functions with Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is there a way to disable access to specific functions in Firefox?
For example, if a website attempts to call "Window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()," can I provide some kind of filter which ignores the function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. If you attach a function to the window, it is available in the browser to anybody. Anybody can open up the console and run that function at any time. This should not really be an issue, security or otherwise.

If you feel that this is a real issue for you, or something that you need, then explain in more detail the exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking is to block certain functions in firefox browser, you can yes. As here, after checking whether your browser is firefox or not, you can set empty functions that you want not to perform any operations.

```
var is_firefox = /firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
if(is_firefox){
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges = function(){};
}
```